# Funcion en appscript con relacion a sheets

Tags: api, lista, google-apps-script, google-api

tengo problemas con una api, solo necesito realizar una función en App script para relacionar una hoja de calculo de google (sheets) con la parte de administración de Google
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gk8G7.png)

Necesito que me genere la lista de grupos de la parte de administración desde el directorio, solo seria eso, que me genere la lista en la hoja de sheets de los campos que tengo en administración de Google
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDLwm.png)

```
function groupadress() {
    try{
    //Lista de los grupos
  var values = [];
  var Gru = AdminDirectory.Group.list({domain:'saviasaludeps.com',  orderBy: 'email', maxResults: 500, showDeleted: true, projection: "full"}).groups; 
  for (var i=0; i<Gru.length; i++){
    values.push([Gru[i].primaryEmail, Gru[i].groupname,Gru[i].members, Gru[i].acesstype]);   //cuando showDeleted está en true, no se puede incluir el nombre
  }
  var libro =SpreadsheetApp.openById('1v4ck_-ANfyd9jysfWS4p8lHcEZVTSa_RSNcu_h_hvLY');
  sheet = libro.getSheetByName('GroupAdress');
  
  var headers = ['Dirección de correo electrónico', 'Nombre  del grupo', 'Miembros', 'Tipo de acceso'];
  sheet.clear()
  sheet.appendRow(headers); 
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
    .alert('Función ejecutada exitosamente');  
    
    
    } catch(e){
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
    .alert('Se produjo el error ' + e.message +  'en la función');

      }
    
}
```

Esperaba que me generara la lista que tengo en administración de grupos de Google con los campos que están ahí requeridos

Answer (score 1):

Veo un par de errores. El primero es que el servicio de AdminDirectory contiene una propiedad llamada "Groups" en vez de "Group". Segundo, las propiedades de cada elemento "Group" son diferentes a las que estás usando, y tercero, el "Access Type" no está disponible a través de este servicio. El código queda de la siguiente manera:

```
function groupadress() {
  try{
    //Lista de los grupos
    var values = [];
    var Gru = AdminDirectory.Groups.list({domain:'saviasaludeps.com', orderBy: 'email', maxResults: 500, showDeleted: true, projection: "full"}).groups; 
    for(var i=0; i<Gru.length; i++){
      values.push([Gru[i].email, Gru[i].name, Gru[i].directMembersCount]);   //cuando showDeleted está en true, no se puede incluir el nombre
    }
    var libro = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Lrjv0r-uA7o5aLorji7-cJAohng1-bJwP_qurpdK4aE');
    var sheet = libro.getSheetByName('GroupAdress');

    var headers = ['Dirección de correo electrónico', 'Nombre  del grupo', 'Miembros', 'Tipo de acceso'];
    sheet.clear()
    sheet.appendRow(headers); 
    sheet.getRange(2, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .alert('Función ejecutada exitosamente');  


  } catch(e){
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .alert('Se produjo el error ' + e.message +  'en la función');

  }

}
```